# How to create Django-Rest-framework permission interface like django-admin provide | is there any library available for that?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-authentication, django-permissions

How to create a User interface like django-admin provide for granting/revoking permissions for Django-Rest APIs.
and automatically handle it.
I mean I need a generic functionality, admin user can grant/revoke permissions or APIs to a particular group.

I am searching from last 3 hours but found nothing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create one permission model add two fields 
1. name of the permission
2. slug
now create one or two entries and take the dumb of that table(make fixtures).
name your slug such a way that you can identify which slug of for which field. in **BasePermission** class will get you a request params and from that, you can match that slug with that params if match then allow it(return true) else throw permission error by returning false.
I used the same approach in my project and it works.